# Deserializing a Unity prefab/scene as nested hashtable of key/value pairs

Tags: unity-game-engine, yamldotnet

I'm trying to write a tool that scans through our Unity (2017.4.22) prefabs and scene files to look for Monobehaviour properties that don't exist in a release build. I've created a c# console project (incorporating YamlDotNet 6.1.2), and from this project I refer to Unity's 'Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll' and 'Assembly-CSharp.dll' dlls.

I was wondering if anyone has been able to configure YamlDotNet to parse any given prefab/scene file into a generic key/value data structure (with an arbitrary number of nested levels) in memory, so I can iterate it and use reflection to determine if fields exist.

If you're wondering why I need to do this manually, it's because I'm scanning for fields that don't exist in release builds. The only way to do that is to recompile 'Assembly-CSharp-firstpass' and 'Assembly-CSharp' with UNITY_EDITOR removed (and all code from files within a 'Editor' subfolder) culled. I can't do this in-editor (obviously) so that's why this has to be a standalone tool.

Everything I've tried has resulted in crashes. Here's what I tried:

1. I downloaded the YamlDotNet 6.1.2 source
2. Tried to deserialize a prefab using Deserialize(...). Received this error: "Encountered an unresolved tag 'tag:unity3d.com,2011:1'"
3. I then found this custom Type resolver, which I integrated: https://gist.github.com/derFunk/795d7a366627d59e0dbd
4. I then started receiving this exception: "Exception during deserialization ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to create an instance of type 'UnityEngine.GameObject'"

I'm guessing this is is happening because I'm trying to instantiate a GameObject in an environment that doesn't fully support GameObjects (I am in a standalone C# project after all).

But I don't actually need to instantiate any GameObjects. I just want to parse the values. Does this make sense to anyone? I found a few other questions here but they don't seem to handle YAML files that are at the same complexity as Unity's prefabs.

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Because you are resolving the `tag:unity3d.com,2011:*` tags to `UnityEngine.GameObject` and related types, then the deserializer attempts to create an instance of the corresponding type when it encounters the tags.

You could opt to always resolve the tag to `Dictionary<string, object>` (or `Dictionary<object, object>` if the keys are not always strings). Then always get dictionaries.

In your case it is probably simpler to load the YAML stream using `YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlStream`. This will give you a representation of the YAML document that will be more suitable for your use case.

Here's the official example on how to do it: https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Samples.LoadingAYamlStream

```
// Load the stream
var yaml = new YamlStream();
yaml.Load(input);

// Examine the stream
var mapping = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had trouble sleeping last night and stumbled on exactly the sample code on your site. So now I'm a little embarrassed :D